# Call the actual association in an ActiveRecord redefined association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  def company
    # Do something here

    # Call the actual association (that would be usually returned by calling User#company)
  end
end
```

I’m aware that I could use another internal name for the association but want to avoid that.

I’m pretty sure there is some kind of internal method that Rails calls when you call the plain association `User#company` method and I want to call it myself in my redefined `User#company` method here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `super` in your method. Or `association(:company)` or `associations(:company)` (I forgot which one). Or you can

```
def company_with_my_stuff
  company_without_my_stuff
end
alias_method_chain :company, :my_stuff
```

Also you could rename the `belongs_to :original_company, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => "company_id"` which I think is a better solution.

Comment: Oh, I never thought about calling `super`… That did the trick. Thank you!